# I can't seem to print out the character type matrix

Tags: c, arrays, loops, matrix, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int row, col, i, j, n;
    char U;
    char **board;

    printf("Enter number of dimensions: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    row = n;
    col = n;

    board = malloc(row*sizeof(char *));
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {       
        board[i] = malloc(col*sizeof(char));
        if(board[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("Out of memory");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j<n; j++)
        {
            board [i][j] = U;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j<n; j++)
        {
            printf("%c",board[i][j]);
        }
    }

}
```

I have just learned malloc, and I only have knowledge of stdio.h functions, pointers, arrays, loops, making my own functions, and math.h functions. I don't know realloc or calloc, is there anything I can do to this to make it print out the character U in an nxn matrix, with the user inputting n. (using Carter book for C)

Comment: I never seen `U` being initialized. Where does its value come from?

Comment: Don't forget a printf("\n"); after printing each row.

Comment: Side note: Consider rather than `ptr = malloc(n * sizeof(type))`, use `ptr = malloc(n * sizeof(*ptr))`.  Example: `board = malloc(row * sizeof(*board))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j<n; j++)
        {
            board [i][j] = U;
        }
    }
```

It should be like that

```
for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j<n; j++)
        {
            board [i][j] = 'U';
        }
    }
```

you are missing quotes for char.

Answer (score 1):

Compile with warnings:

```
warning: ‘U’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

Also, note that `sizeof(char)` is always 1

Use `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` instead of `return 0` when `malloc` fails